# Android - Cannot get location using Network Provider when using APN

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

We have developed an Android Application. One of the main features of it is report the user location to the server. The location receiving function tries to get GPS location for a few seconds and switches to Network Provider (if available).

The problem is, the client devices use an APN which only allows connection with the back-end server. The location accessing algorithm gets stuck at accessing location using Network Provider.

Only using GPS or ignoring user location are not an option.

I get the feeling this is something that has to be done by the service provider. They asked me if they have to allow access to any particular domain/IP from their firewall.

How exactly does the Network Provider gets the location? Does the function require any network calls to any particular server so I can inform them to allow access to it?